# How can I have two many-to-many relationships to the same model in DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, many-to-many, datamapper

**edit:** Updated question to show my use of `:child_key => [:comparison_id]` as suggested in the comment.

I have two models that look like this:

```
class Comparison
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
end

class Msrun
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
end
```

Comparison come from comparing two sets of Msruns. I thought I would represent this through two many-to-many relationships from Comparison to Msrun, but I am beating my head against the wall as to how to do this in DataMapper. I know that many-to-many relationships are available by adding something like this:

```
has n, :whatevers, :through => Resource
```

However, this will only make one many-to-many relationship between the two models. I have also tried creating two join models and manually specifying the relationships, and manually specifying the child key for each relationship like so:

```
# Join model for the comparison-msrun many-to-many relationship.
class First
  include DataMapper::Resource
  belongs_to :msrun, :key => true
  belongs_to :comparison, :key => true
end


# Join model for the comparison-msrun many-to-many relationship.
class Second
  include DataMapper::Resource
  belongs_to :msrun, :key => true
  belongs_to :comparison, :key => true
end

class Comparison
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial

  has n, :firsts
  has n, :msrun_firsts, 'Msrun', :through => :firsts, :child_key => [:msrun_id]

  has n, :seconds
  has n, :msruns_seconds, 'Msrun', :through => :seconds, :child_key => [:msrun_id]
end

class Msrun
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String

  has n, :firsts
  has n, :comparison_firsts, 'Comparison', :through => :firsts, :child_key => [:comparison_id]

  has n, :seconds
  has n, :comparison_seconds, 'Comparison', :through => :seconds, :child_key => [:comparison_id]
end
```

Running `automigrate` results in the following error:

```
rake aborted!
No relationships named msrun_firsts or msrun_first in First
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

As per the DataMapper [docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations)

I believe you can do:

```
class Msrun
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :name, String

    has n, :firsts #This line could probably be omitted 
    has n, :first_comparisons, 'Comparison', :through => :firsts

    has n, :seconds #This line could probably be omitted 
    has n, :second_comparisons, 'Comparison', :through => :seconds
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear. I have tried that, and I get the following error: No relationships named first_msruns or first_msrun in First

Comment: To avoid naming errors you must specify `has n, :firsts, ... :child_key => [ :msrun_id ]` for `Msrun` and `has n, :firsts, ... :child_key => [ :comparison_id ]` for `Comparison`.
`:child_key` is needed to bind fields with different names.

Answer (score 0):

What you're observing, is the fact that relationships are stored in a set like object under the hood, more specifically, a set that uses the relationship's name as discriminator. So what happens in your case, is that the latter definition overwrites the former, as sets don't allow duplicate entries (and in our case, replace the older entry with the newer, for the set's purposes, identical one).

There are practical reasons for this. It makes no sense to declare two supposedly different relationships on one model, but name them the same. How would you distinguish them when trying to access them? This manifests itself in DM's implementation, where a method named by the relationship name gets defined on the Resource. So what DM ends up doing in your case of trying to add a duplicate to the set, is that it will just use the latter options to generate the implementation of that method. Even if it were to accept duplicate relationship names, the latter relationship would lead to an overwritten/redefined version of the same method, thus leaving you with the same net effect.

As a consequence, you would need to define differently named relationships on your models. When you think about it, it really makes sense. To help DM with inferring the model to use, you can pass the model name (or the constant itself) as the 3rd parameter to the `has` method, or as the 2nd parameter for `belongs_to`

```
class Comparison
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial

  has n, :firsts
  has n, :first_msruns, 'Msrun', :through => :firsts

  has n, :seconds
  has n, :second_msruns, 'Msrun', :through => :seconds
end

class Msrun
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String

  has n, :firsts
  has n, :first_comparisons, 'Comparison', :through => :firsts

  has n, :seconds
  has n, :second_comparisons, 'Comparison', :through => :seconds

end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does that code work successfully for you? That gives me the following error: No relationships named first_msruns or first_msrun in First.